# Can't see or load raster data in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal

First time install and use for QGIS, running windows 7

In QGIS browser or through project>open I can not see any raster files/data, only vector data is shown. I do see them in ArcMap.

When I try to load raster data that is displayed from sample data included with installation I get the following error

> Invalid Layer: GDAL provider Cannot open GDAL dataset
>   C:/Users/Izak/Documents/GIS
>   DataBase/spearfish60/PERMANENT/cell/elevation.dem:
>   `C:/Users/Izak/Documents/GIS
>   DataBase/spearfish60/PERMANENT/cell/elevation.dem' not recognized as a
>   supported file format. Raster layer Provider is not valid (provider:
>   gdal, URI: C:/Users/Izak/Documents/GIS
>   DataBase/spearfish60/PERMANENT/cell/elevation.dem

I've tried both QGIS 3.4 and 3.6 with standalone installer and the OSGeoW4 Network installer.

Could someone please help. I really do want to make the shift from Arc to Qgis

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Have you tried loading different raster data, e.g. a `.tiff`-file? Have you verified that QGIS is able to open `.dem`-files? Have you tried converting the `.dem` to any other raster-format?

Comment: Thanks Erik. It does load .img and .tif files. It won't load .dem files. I also cannot see .dem files in browser. The files I'm trying to laod are stored in .gdb, not sure if that is problem

Comment: Is this sample data from QGIS or ArcGIS? I don't see any mention of a file called "elevation.dem" in the [QGIS Training Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/data_manipulation.html#basic-fa-loading-raster-data). Also, `.dem` is not mentioned on [this list of GDAL-supported raster formats](https://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html). It might help if you provide a list of the sample data files included in your download.

Comment: The sample data is from the QGIS standalone installer. It makes sense if .dem is not supported file. Why can I not see my DEM's and raster data in the browser

Comment: Okay I think the first part of the problem is that I'm trying to open files that are not a supported format. 

I still have the problem that I can not see any of my raster data in QGIS browser